# Солирование паролей пользователей

Tags: база-данных, безопасность

Есть таблица с пользователями, в колонке хранится зашифрованный пароль. Я хочу, чтобы каждый пользователь имел свою соль, а не общую, для лучшей безопасности. Как это лучше реализовать? Иметь дополнительную колонку для солей, или сделать какую-нибудь функцию для генерации уникальной соли? Я не хочу использовать функцию, т.к. тут трудности что брать за параметр (имя (меняется), дату регистрации (может быть общая), id - слишком простое значение). Подскажите у кого есть опыт.

Comment: Колонку свою с солью

Comment: Уточнить, нет ли чего-нибудь штатного более подходящего в используемом вами языке или фреймворке. password_hash для php, например.

Comment: @Мелкий Если всегда использовать только штатное, то в чем тогда развитие... Я знаю про то, что уже есть готовые md5-функции и т.д. Хотелось бы самой это уметь делать

Comment: @AzizUmarov, а пояснить?

Comment: Генерируете соль каждый раз добавляете соль в текст с нужных сторон (что есть тоже логика) и хешируете, при этом сохраняя соль в базе для дальнейшего вопроизведения.

Comment: @Helen, а для саморазвития изучать криптографию. В частности, почему в хэшировании паролей md5 не используют. А берут что-то очень весьма более медленное.

Answer (score 0):

дополнительная колонка для соли.

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#salting

Имхо, соль не обязательно должна быть уникальной, т.е. не нужно по ней создавать уникальный констрейнт. Куда важнее ее случайность.
Генерировать соль лучше всего безопасным генератором случайных чисел. Например:

```
static final SecureRandom PRNG = new SecureRandom();
static final int SALT_SIZE = 16; // length of your salt column

// ...

byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_SIZE];
PRNG.nextBytes(salt);
```

но это нужно только в том случае, если использовать классические хэш алгоритмы, если же взять к примеру BCrypt то соль будет закодирована в хэш, т.е. дополнительная колонка будет не нужна.